# Sharing data between components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-services

getting issue in component data sharing. i have 2 components, they don't have parent child relationship. in my sidebar component i have a checkbox, by clicking this checkbox i want to perform some action in my dashboard component.

**sidebar component**

```
  manageWidgetLocation(){
  this.togglewidgetService.toggleSideNav(true);
  }
```

**dashboard component**

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.togglewidgetService.onSideNavToggle()
        .subscribe(
         (opening) => {
                       debugger;
                       if (opening) {
                          console.log(">>>>>>>here");
                       } else {
                          //Logic to close the sidenav here
                        }
                   }
                );
            }

     open(sidenav) {
                  sidenav.open();
                                 }

    close(sidenav) {
              sidenav.close();
                               }
```

**service**

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"

    import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs/Rx";

    @Injectable()
    export class toggleWidgetService {

      private sidenavOpenSubject : Subject<boolean>;

     constructor() {
       this.sidenavOpenSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
                                                        }

      toggleSideNav(opening: boolean): void {
      this.sidenavOpenSubject.next(opening);
                                            }

      onSideNavToggle(): Observable<boolean> {
       return this.sidenavOpenSubject;
                                          }

              }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585998/angular-2-how-to-share-array-data-between-components-using-service

Comment: Are both components and service is in a separate module?

Comment: @John Velasquez yes

Comment: Check the approach of creating a `subject` in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thlr64?file=app%2Fapp.component.html.  Hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898893/angular-eventemitter-from-component-to-app-component/49899011#49899011. You can create a `common` module which has a subject which is being `subscribed` by other module components

Answer (score 1):

My best advice is to create a **CoreModule** that represents a single instance module, and create a **pub/sub** service to share data across your modules.

**CoreModule**

```
import {
    ModuleWithProviders, NgModule,
    Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

//Providers
import { PubSubService } from './pub-sub.service';


/**
 * This module handles all the singleton services
 */
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [PubSubService]
})
export class CoreModule {
    constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error(
                'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
        }
    }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: CoreModule,
            providers: [PubSubService]
        };
    }
}
```

**PubSubService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

/**
 * Publisher/Subscriber Service
 */
@Injectable()
export class PubSubService {

    private events: any = {};

    constructor() { }

    /**
     * Subscribes the instance of the assigned event name
     * @param eventName
     * Event name of the delegate
     */
    public On(eventName: PubSubEvents): Observable<any> {

        if (typeof this.events[eventName] === 'undefined') {
            this.events[eventName] = new Subject<any>();
        }

        return this.events[eventName].asObservable();
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast data to the specified event channel
     * @param eventName
     * Event name of the delegate
     * @param eventArgs
     * Arguments to pass through the connected channel
     */
    public Broadcast(eventName: PubSubEvents, eventArgs: any) {
        if (!this.events[eventName]) {
            return;
        }

        this.events[eventName].next(eventArgs);
    }





}

//Your events
export declare type PubSubEvents = "OnSideNavToggle" | "OnAnyOtherEvent1" | "OnAnyOtherEvent2";
```

**How to use**

> Make sure CoreModule is only imported once, import it in AppModule

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**sidebar component**

```
toggle: boolean = false;
constructor(private pubsub: PubSubService){

}

manageWidgetLocation(){
   this.boolean  = !this.boolean;
  this.pubsub.Broadcast("OnSideNavToggle", this);
}
```

**dashboard component**

```
constructor(private pubsub: PubSubService){
  this.pubsub.On("OnSideNavToggle").subscribe((res) =>{
    //res -> value of the toggle state
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**service**

```
@Injectable()
export class toggleWidgetService {
  sidenavOpenSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

**dashboard**

```
constructor(private service: BlaService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.sidenavOpenSubject.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.log(error)
  )
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.service.sidenavOpenSubject.unsubscribe()
}
```

**sidebar**

```
constructor(private service: Service) {}

someFunction() {
  this.service.sidenavOpenSubject.next(true);
}
```

this will work just fine.

Comment: thanks for your reply but this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

In service:

```
 Make observable of your sidenavOpenSubject variable as =>

    subject_observable = this.sidenavOpenSubject.asObservable();
```

In Dashboard Component:

```
Try to subscribe subject_observable as =>    

this.togglewidgetService.subject_observable.subscribe(   opening =>
  {
 // 
  } )
```

Comment: can you explain the service part. not getting u.

Comment: Here, we are declaring the observable,such that when any change is encountered in value of sidenavOpenSubject, it can be listened in dashboard component.